# $\int_{-2}^2\frac{x^2}{x^4+1} \sin(2x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Please, without using that the function is odd on [-2,2] then the integral is 0, is there an other method to calculate the integral $\int_{-2}^2\frac{x^2}{x^4+1} \sin(2x)dx$ ?

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like a function where we can easily find a primitive. Anyway, why don't you want to use the fact that the function is odd?

Comment: i have to do it. into two different methods @Mark

Comment: Without using $1+(-1)=0,$ is there another method to calculate $1+(-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

How about:
$$I(t)=\int_{-2}^2\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}\sin(tx)dx$$
$$I'(t)=\int_{-2}^2\frac{x^3\cos(tx)}{x^4+1}dx=\left[\frac 14\ln|x^4+1|\cos(tx)\right]_{x=-2}^2+\frac 14\int_{-2}^2\ln(x^4+1)t\sin(tx)dx$$
$$I'(t)=\frac{\ln 17}{2}\cos(2t)+\frac 14\int_{-2}^2\ln(x^4+1)\sin(tx)tdx$$
$$I(T)-\int_{-2}^2\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}dx=\frac{\ln 17}{2}\int_0^T\cos(2t)dt+\frac 14\int_0^T\int_{-2}^2\ln(x^4+1)\sin(tx)tdxdt$$
Now try changing the order of integration in the final integral or using $u,v$ substitution to obtain a result. Once you get a formula for $I(t)$ notice that your original integral is just $I(2)$